# How to create an external table using variables in Synapse without specifying columns

Tags: sql, azure, stored-procedures, azure-synapse

I have a stored procedure in Synapse Dedicated pool which takes a parquet file from adls and creates a staging table in dedicated pool:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Staging_Tables_sp
(
    @TableName VARCHAR(MAX),
    @SchemaName VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN

    EXEC ('SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
   
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [' + @SchemaName + '].[Staging_' + @TableName +']
    WITH (
    LOCATION = N''/Folder/ParquetFiles/' + @TableName + '/'',
    DATA_SOURCE = [gold_parquet],
    FILE_FORMAT = [ParquetFormat],
    REJECT_TYPE = VALUE,
    REJECT_VALUE = 0)');
END
```

Execute statement:

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar(max)
DECLARE @SchemaName varchar(max)
 
 
 EXECUTE [dbo].[Staging_Tables_sp]
    @TableName = 'Table',
    @SchemaName = 'Schema'
```

When I try to execute it I get the following error:

> Parse error at line: 10, column: 22: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL, to include a single quote character in a string, you need to escape it by doubling it, you did it at the beginning of the line, but it is missed at the end

So, you can modify this line

```
LOCATION = N''/Folder/ParquetFiles/' + @TableName + '/'',
```

With this

```
LOCATION = N''/Folder/ParquetFiles/' + @TableName + '/''',
```

Comment: I've tried that before but continue to get the same error. I was guessing that escaping the string was the issue but it continues to happen. I've tried removing the parameter and just passing the table name and just printing the string to see if it looks weird but the error persists, when I printed the string it all looked normal though.

Answer (score 0):

I got your example working by adding a 'select' to query the parquet file using a view.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [' + @SchemaName + '].[Staging_' + @TableName +']
WITH (
LOCATION = N''/results/' + @TableName + '/'',
DATA_SOURCE = [ResultsDataSource],
FILE_FORMAT = [CSV])
AS
SELECT * FROM vwContacts');
```

view:

```
CREATE VIEW vwContacts
AS SELECT * FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://[mystorage].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/contacts.parquet',
        FORMAT='PARQUET'
    ) as [contacts]
GO
```